# Node js api can not read the data from curl request via php

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter

I'm trying to post a request from PHP curl but I'm not getting any response from API.AND this API is working fine in postman.
Here is my code...

```
$username   =   trim($this->request->getVar('username'));
$password   =   $this->request->getVar('password');
$data       =   json_encode(array("email"=>$username,"password"=>$password));

$curl       = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => API_URL.'/user/login',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($data)
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: _"I'm not getting any response from API"_ - Have you done any debugging, like checking what headers you get in the response? What status code does the API return?

Comment: not getting any status code